# Rails - why is /public/assets gitignored when I need this for static imaged

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

In my Rails (Rails 7) app, I have some small assets (a logo and a favicon), which I want to render in production as well as in development.

I put the assets in /app/assets/images.

Since setting `# config.assets.compile = true` is not recommended, i run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. It then builds a whole lot of files (it runs `esbuild app/javascript/application.tsx` since I have a typescript react app running in this rails app.) and puts them in `/public/assets/`. But this folder is `.gitignore`d by default. Since the folder is approx 5.5 Mb I can see why. Now, heroku docs tell me to add `/public/assets/` to git and then my assets should show, but why then is this directory gitignored by default?

Am I missing something? Should I just remove the dir from my .gitignore file?

Or could I just put the assets in the `public` folder directly? If so, how do I add an image referencing the public folder in an erb file?

Comment: Its ignored as you would typically generate the assets after deployment. Heroku did this with previous versions of Rails through its [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) which performs a number of steps after you push your app (this is why deploying to Heroku was so smooth and effortless). Adding the compiled assets to your repository is undesirable as it greatly increases the amount of noise in your git history.

Comment: "Or could I just put the assets in the public folder directly?" - yes you can absolutely do this. However you'll lose the cache busting feature provided by having asset digests.

Answer (score 2):

The home for static assets is the `/public` folder. In a default Rails 7 app you will find some error pages (e.g. `/public/404.html`) and icons (e.g. `/public/favicon.ico`) already in that folder. Files in this folder will be available both directly, `example.com/favicon.ico`, and under the public path, `example.com/public/favicon.ico`. Serving public files can be disabled, see below.

To answer your sub-question, "how do I add an image referencing the public folder in an erb file?" you need to make sure you tell Rails it's an absolute path, not a relative one somewhere in the asset pipeline. This is done with a leading forward slash.

The following compares including a logo called `logo.png` when it's stored in `app/assets/images` vs `/public`

```
<%= image_tag "logo.png" %>
<!-- becomes <img src="/assets/logo-1f04fdc3ec379029cee88d56e008774df299be776f88e7a9fe5.png"> or similar -->


<%= image_tag "/logo.png" %>
<!-- note the leading slash. This becomes <img src="/logo.png"> -->

<img src="/logo.png">
<!-- or use plain HTML if you don't need/want to use the helper -->
```

You can also use sub-directories; `/public/images/logo.png` would be available at `/images/logo.png` (or `image_tag "/images/logo.png"`).

The second paragraph of chapter 2 of [The Asset Pipeline Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) contians more information. It mentions that this functionality depends on whether `config.public_file_server.enabled` is set.

In Rails 7 that config defaults to `ENV["RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES"].present?` in `config/production.rb`. If you're using Heroku you can check this variable with `heroku config:get RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES`.

The guide also has more information on how to adjust all this behaviour to have these files served by your upstream web server (e.g. nginx) or from a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, I went with adding the assets to the public folder directly and this works fine. It would be nice though if Heroku would either support a way to generate the assets after deployment by default, or describe an option to do it like I did in their docs.